# How to set a local variable for a filtered select?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to save the result of a column c1 in a variable x but after filtering that select :

```
select @x=c1 , c2 from table where contains(c2,"text")
```

when i run that i get this error :

```
a select statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be combined with data extraction operations
```

what i understand that i can't  select a column to filter and assign a variable in the same select ,any idea on  how to do that  ?

Comment: `select top 1`?

Comment: Use an outer select-from.

Comment: what do you mean ?

Comment: It is not possible. You have to use two statements. Why do you want to assign a variable, and select columns in the same statement?

Comment: @GarethD i need to pass the return  of that column  to another sql request (insert)

Comment: *"any idea on how to do that?"* You don't; you assign or you return data, not both. If you need to do both, you need to use 2 separate statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this test

> ```
> create table test (
>  c1 int, 
>  c2 varchar(30)
> );
>
> insert into test(c1, c2) values 
> (1,'foo'),
> (2,'foo'),
> (3,'bar');
> ```

> ```
> declare @x int;
>
> select @x = c1, c2
> from test
> where c2 = 'bar';
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> Msg 141 Level 15 State 1 Line 3
> A SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be combined with data-retrieval operations.
> ```

> ```
> declare @x int;
>
> select @x = c1
> from test
> where c2 = 'bar';
>
> select 'attempt 1' as tst, @x as x;
>
> select @x = c1
> from test
> where c2 = 'foo';
>
> select 'attempt 2' as tst, @x as x;
>
> select top 1 @x = c1
> from test
> where c2 = 'foo'
> order by c1;
>
> select 'attempt 3' as tst, @x as x;
>
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> tst       |  x
> :-------- | -:
> attempt 1 |  3
>
> tst       |  x
> :-------- | -:
> attempt 2 |  2
>
> tst       |  x
> :-------- | -:
> attempt 3 |  1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2f53c1ef8597cc76b4fb8ba845873633)*

You'll notice that the error is raised when you're trying to select other columns beside the variable assignment.

But having multiple records retrieved isn't a problem.
In the end, the variable will only receive 1 value.

If you do need to get the result from a query, then do it separately.

For example:

```
declare @x int;

select @x = c1 from test where c2 like '%bar%';

select c1, c2 from test where c1 = @x;
```

Or use more than 1 variable

```
declare @x int;
declare @y varchar(30)

select top 1 @x = c1, @y = c2 
from test 
where c2 like '%foo%'
order by c1 desc;

select @x as x, @y as y;
```